# regex replace '?' in the middle or beginning of a word

Tags: regex, replace

I am having trouble formulating a regex expression that
would replace occurrences of "?" in the middle or beginning
of words.
Lets say I have this piece of text:

```
?this
tha?t
midd?le
?beginning
```

And I want to replace all occurrences  "?" with "x", so it will become

```
xthis
thaxt
middxle
xbeginning
```

I'm specifically looking for ? in the beginning or middle of words because
if it's in the end of a word/row it is literally a ? and not an unknown character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookahead to make sure `?` is not at the end using:

```
\?(?!$)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex to match all the `?` which are not at the the end of a word or a sentence.  Then replace the matched `?` symbols with `x`

```
\?(?!\s|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to match `\?\b`, because `\b` only matches between a non-alphanumeric character (like `?`) and an alphanumeric character (like a letter).

```
>>> s = """?this
... tha?t
... midd?le
... ?beginning
... end?
... even this???
... """
>>> print(re.sub(r"\?\b", "x", s))
xthis
thaxt
middxle
xbeginning
end?
even this???
```